# Using a key taken from an input and using it to recall a value

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

The project is based on a cashier. When an input is accepted, it gets stored. I have used this to determine whether an item is in the dictionary or not.
I am currently stuck on how to implement the input as a key to recall the corresponding value in a defined dictionary.
Is there any way to do this using the tools I've used, or is a more complicated function required? My code is underneath, and the **very last line seems to be the problem**. Thanks.

my_dictionary = {"Chips", 1}

#Taking order

order = input("What do you want? \n")

#Recalling order

if order in my_dictionary:

print(f"Okay you want {order}")

else:

print("We dont have that please leave")
exit()

#Gving price

print(my_dictionary["order"])

Comment: That's not a dictionary, that's a set.

Comment: Once you fix the above, `my_dictionary[order]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I have written that checks if the order the user inputs is:

1. In your dictionary.
2. In stock.

Python is case sensitive so I have added the .title() method to the user input to convert the string to title case. This is because the 'Chips' in your dictionary is also in title case.

```
my_dictionary = {
"Chips" : 1
}

order = input("What do you want?\n").title()

if order in my_dictionary:
    if my_dictionary[order] == 0:
        print("We don't have that, please leave.")
else:
        print(f"Okay you want, {order}")
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the case sensitivity issue; I've opted for using the .lower() method, as I realised an issue when accidentally typing inputs in cap lock. I've also realised an error in discussing my error, the value in the dictionary is the price, not the stock number, but that'll add an extra dimension to my project when I figure out how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the `" "` around order like: `my_dictionary[order]` in your last `print()` function.

Answer (score 0):

---

I've opted to use this code for the time being, having solved the issue:

```
my_dictionary = {"chips", 1}

order = input("What do you want?\n").lower()

if order in my_dictionary:
   
    print(f"Ok you want {order}")

else:

    print("We dont have that, leave")
```